# Regular Expressions (regex) cause program to crash

Tags: c#, regex

I am using a program which takes a .csv file and converts it into an .SGM (sgml) file which is in accordance with a specific schema/dtd we use.

Unfortunately the tool which does the conversion puts several of the elements in the wrong order when converting to SGML, so I wrote some regex to correct this. I was using a program called 'Advanced find and Replace' for writing and testing the regex (an excellent program that I have used for years), and I have subsequently written a Windows app in C# which does the same thing.

All works absolutely perfectly, for the equivalent of 43 lines of the csv file. Any more than this, and either program crashes (the Advanced find Replace, and my own Windows app). The .SGM file I'm running the regex on is around 12Kb - so tiny.

It's clearly not the regex itself as it works on fewer lines of data. It seems to be when I add the 43rd line in the CSV file and convert that to SGML, then run the regex, that my troubles begin. And no, it's nothing to do with the line of data itself.

Here are my regex queries which run one after the other, (yes I'm new to regex so they may not be overly efficient).

Any pointers or ideas what's happening please?

```
SearchFor=<iplnom>(.*?)<nom>(.*?)<\/nom>
ReplaceWith=<iplnom><nom>$2</nom>$1

SearchFor=<iplnom><nom>(.*?)<\/nom>(.*?)<mfr>(.*?)<\/mfr>
ReplaceWith=<iplnom><nom>$1</nom><mfr>$3</mfr>$2

SearchFor=<iplnom><nom>(.*?)<\/mfr>(.*?)<mdl>(.*?)<\/mdl>
ReplaceWith=<iplnom><nom>$1</mfr><mdl>($3)</mdl>$2

SearchFor=<iplnom><nom>(.*?)<\/mdl>(.*?)<fds>(.*?)<\/fds>
ReplaceWith=<iplnom><nom>$1</mdl><fds>$3</fds>$2

SearchFor=<iplnom><nom>(.*?)<\/fds>(.*?)<alprtmfr>(.*?)<\/alprtmfr>
ReplaceWith=<iplnom><nom>$1</fds><alprtmfr>$3</alprtmfr>$2

SearchFor=<iplnom><nom>(.*?)<\/alprtmfr>(.*?)<msc>(.*?)<\/msc>
ReplaceWith=<iplnom><nom>$1</alprtmfr><msc>$3</msc>$2

SearchFor=<iplnom><nom>(.*?)<\/msc>(.*?)<uoi>(.*?)<\/uoi>
ReplaceWith=<iplnom><nom>$1</msc><uoi>$3</uoi>$2

SearchFor=<iplnom><nom>(.*?)<\/uoi>(.*?)<esds>(.*?)<\/esds>
ReplaceWith=<iplnom><nom>$1</uoi><esds>$3</esds>$2

SearchFor=<msc><\/msc>
ReplaceWith=

SearchFor=<esds><\/esds>
ReplaceWith=

SearchFor=<osc><\/osc>
ReplaceWith=

SearchFor=<uoi><\/uoi>
ReplaceWith=

SearchFor=<mdl>\(\)<\/mdl>
ReplaceWith=

SearchFor=<alprtmfr><altpn><\/altpn><mfr><\/mfr><\/alprtmfr>
ReplaceWith=

SearchFor=<alprtmfr><altpn><\/altpn><\/alprtmfr>
ReplaceWith=

SearchFor=<mfr><\/mfr>
ReplaceWith=

SearchFor=<fds><\/fds>
ReplaceWith=
```

Comment: Where is the C# code?  I don't see how we can answer this.

Comment: This looks like you are dealing with XML.  I suggest you use a XML parser instead of regular expressions.

Comment: @juharr SGML only looks like XML.  He should be using an SGML parser.

Comment: The C# is irrelevant in this case as it's also crashing the 'Advanced Find and Replace' when I run the regex with that. The C# program works fine on fewer lines of data as well. In other words it's not the code, it's the regex causing the problem somehow.

Comment: I'm confused, are you converting sgml to csv or csv to sgml? Your question appears to say both. Also when you say crashing what do you mean? Is it throwing an error, running out of stack space, going into an infinite loop? Lastly, though this may not be the issue, it smells a bit like  a 'Catastrophic Backtracking' issue see http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: Thanks @MartinBrown, the 'off the shelf' tool initially converts the .csv file to SGML. It builds the elements etc. but builds some of them in the wrong order. My regex is run on the SGML file in order to correct the elements using backreferences as you can see. I know there are probably better ways (parsers etc) but I was looking for a 'quick and dirty way' way to correct it. And it works, but only for a limited amount of data. The C# program seems to go into infinite loop. No errors. Catastrophic backtracking may be the problem, i'll have to look into it as I'm not overly familiar.

Comment: Not sure, but do you think replacing the first regex "<iplnom>(.*?)<nom>(.*?)<\/nom>" with "(<iplnom>)(?!\/nom).*" would reduce iteration steps for a match? If so we can apply the same concept for all other relevant regexes.